# Importing Request library in Python

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to use the Python Library requests using Liclipse. I have added the library but it is giving me the below error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\programming\automate_boring_stuff\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
  File "C:\programming\libraries\kennethreitz-requests-> > 00fa5f1\requests\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import ssl_match_hostname
ImportError: cannot import name ssl_match_hostname
```

Unusually I was previously using it on another computer and it worked finebut on this one by just running import requests it gives me the above error message.

I have tried researching this but most of the answers I have found have been related to different libraries and I could not find how the fixes related to the requests library.

Comment: How did you install the library? From your path it looks like you are using a git clone, are you sure it is complete?

Answer (score 2):

You have mucked up your installation; you appear to have moved the [`requests/packages/urllib3/packages/__init__.py` file](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/046a0f215de3fac60326ea1c2c9dd30beb329f61/requests/packages/urllib3/packages/__init__.py) into the top-level `requests` folder.

Remove the package and re-install.